# Testfor specific held item with a certain name and lore?

Tags: minecraft-java-edition, minecraft-commands

I am trying to test if the player is holding a piece of paper named "Ticket" with a lorestring saying that the ticket is not punched. I have the following:

```
/testfor @p[r=10] {SelectedItemSlot:0,Inventory:[{Slot:0b,tag:{display:{Name:"Ticket",Lore:[This is a punched ticket.]}}]}
```

I can get it to work with just the Name but I can't get it to work with both the name and lore. How do I fix this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are missing a closing curly bracket for the item data:

```
/testfor @p[r=10] {SelectedItemSlot:0,Inventory:[{Slot:0b,tag:{display:{Name:"Ticket",Lore:["This is a punched ticket."]}}}]}
```

However, I recommend using the `SelectedItem` compound tag instead of checking for each individual hotbar slot. `SelectedItem` will contain a copy of the player's currently-held item (minus the `Slot` tag), such that you do not need to have multiple command blocks for each slot:

```
/execute if entity @p[distance=..10,nbt={SelectedItem:{tag:{display:{Name:"\"Ticket\"",Lore:["This is a punched ticket."]}}}}] run <command>
```